# How to use two versions of jQuery in same webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use another version of jQuery on the same page on website without conflicts? This is the situation:

```
<!-- code with loaded jquery-2.2.0.min.js -->
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

I need to use jQuery 1.3.0 just for this gallery div, so the best if it'd work like this:

```
<!-- code with jquery-2.2.0.min.js -->
<div id="gallery">
  <!-- load jquery-1.3.0.min.js just on this div -->
</div>
<!-- load jquery-2.2.min.js again to the rest of the site -->
```

I don't know JS nor jQuery, nor how it works, that's why I ask you guys. I can even put full jquery-1.3.0.min.js code on the page somehow, I just need this to work without conflict with jQuery 2.2.0. I also need jQuery 2.2.0 on this page as well.
I need any working solution.

Comment: The best is to use latest one only ....

Comment: I would say it's impossible unless a jQuery Guru say it is ....

Comment: It's possible (see the duplicate I marked for examples) but it's a big headache that's really best avoided. I'd strongly suggest you use a single version of jQuery which you update globally. If jQuery 2.2.0 has issues for you, why use it? I presume it's an IE-related problem as that was the major change to the 2.x branch